# When transaction begins in jdbc connection pool?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

**Preconditions**

- Hikari connection pool
- Oracle database
- Default isolation level (read-commited)
- setAutocomplete(false)
- Our connection from the pool has already been used for some queries (it's not new)

**The question**

When does the next transaction start?

1. right after the previous commit
2. on any first request after the previous commit (even if it's a select statement)
3. on the first change request after the previous commit (like, update, delete, insert)
4. something else ?

Comment: Begins when started. Close.

Comment: @K.Nicholas How to start a transaction in JDBC (which method starts it) ?

Comment: Sorting that out is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Sorting out is what I'm trying to do by asking the question here. There is no any special method that are used for starting transactions in jdbc. Here is a [good article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) to start with.

Comment: Probably you should read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Oracle database transaction starts with the SQL DML command (insert/update/delete) and ends with a commit or a rollback (which rolls back to the most recent commit). A select may read the result of a transaction - committed or uncommitted - but is not part of the transaction itself. There is nothing to do in Java to explicitly open or close a transaction; the transaction is defined only within a session and SQL commands in the database.

Comment: Even selects are executed in a transaction (at least in JDBC).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In that case I don't understand :-) Do the transaction starts on the first select? or do you mean that selects after first DML are in that transaction?

Comment: Without a transaction, it is generally not possible to know which records should be visible or not. A JDBC driver (or the underlying database) will start the transaction when a statement is executed and there is no currently active transaction.

Comment: It sounds like there's maybe a conceptual difference between what constitutes a transaction in JDBC vs what individual databases might consider a transaction? Within Oracle, by default the results of a `select` will always be logically/transactionally consistent as of the moment in time the select is initiated, but that consistency is handled under the hood by the database. It is not dependent on the application to tell it the moment of consistency, though that *can* be done in some cases using `as of` queries...

Comment: ... Regardless, a `select` doesn't constitute a *new* transaction, subject to rollback or commit, from the DB perspective. Within the context of the application, that may be different.